# How to set the orientation of camera in Android for the image to be taken

Tags: android, android-camera2

**I am using Camera2Api**

1. I am able to capture front camera image with this but Image is
   90degree oriented.
2. How to set the params so I get a proper image

---

```
private void openCamera() {
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        Log.e(TAG, "is camera open");
        try {
            cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];
            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
            StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
            assert map != null;
            imageDimension = map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class)[0];
            // Add permission for camera and let user grant the permission
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
                return;
            }
            manager.openCamera(cameraId, stateCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "openCamera X");
    }
```

Comment: can you show me a full soruce code?

Comment: The camera capture usually follows the orientation of the phone - do you mean that you want to capture a portrait image while the phone is in landscape orientation and visa versa?

Comment: For me .... Background camera works for `cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[0];` ....... But for the front `camera cameraId = manager.getCameraIdList()[1];` image gets rotated once i get the image

Answer (score 1):

Please set SENSOR_ORIENTATION option

```
 CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(camera_id);
 StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);

 // you have to set this option
 cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
```